# I have two columns with multiple values that I need to parse out

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so:

```
Make       Model                    Year
----------------------------------------------------    
Toyota     Corolla, Camry, Avalon   2009, 2006, 2011
```

And I would like it to be the following:

```
Make       Model      Year
------------------------------    
Toyota     Corolla    2009
Toyota     Camry      2006
Toyota     Avalon     2011
```

Essentially I would like two columns split up and associated with each other by the order in which they are listed.

Comment: This is not something easy to do in SQL -- it is for working with relational data not parsing text.

Comment: Great thing to do! (I assume you understand that the data should have been stored like that from the beginning.)

Comment: I'd probably write a stored procedure.

Comment: You can use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql but order is not guaranteed

Comment: A follow up on my prior comment -- converting a field to xml to use an xml parsing function **has** to be slower than a purpose oriented approach.  ie if you had a large dataset it would be faster to read the table with a good parsing language and then write it back to the database than to use sql to do parsing.

Answer (score 4):

A parse function which returns a sequence would help here

**Example**

```
Select A.Make
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Model=B1.RetVal
                      ,Year =B2.RetVal
                 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.Model,',') B1
                 Join  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.Year,',')  B2
                   on  B1.RetSeq=B2.RetSeq
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Make    Model   Year
Toyota  Corolla 2009
Toyota  Camry   2006
Toyota  Avalon  2011
```

**The UDF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Comment: I am like the "tvf-Str-Parse". What is the source?

Comment: @DaniDev Me.  The XML parse is not unique.  I did, however, have a need for the sequence, thus the Row_Number().   Also, Shnugo had a post some time ago which makes this approach XML Safe ...  §§Split§§.

Comment: @DaniDev The Tally approach is more performant but limited to 10K.   This can parse varchar(max) and on a sample of 5,000 records it was 19ms slower than the tally.