# Query returns results in designer but not as stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue where if I create a stored procedure it runs but no results are returned.

If I run the same query in the query builder of Visual Studio 2017 it works with correct results returned.

My query is as below:

```
SELECT        
    PersonDetails.FirstName, PersonDetails.MiddleName, 
    PersonDetails.LastName, PersonDetails.DOB, PersonDetails.Gender, 
    CSVToTable_1.String AS SearchedID, 
    DealerTransactions.Address, DealerTransactions.AddressSuburb, 
    DealerTransactions.IDUsed, DealerTransactions.TransactionDate, 
    DealerTransactions.TransactionType, DealerTransactions.Item, 
    DealerTransactions.ItemDescription, DealerTransactions.SerialNumber, 
    DealerTransactions.TransactionNumber, DealerTransactions.ItemAmount, 
    DealerShops.ShopName
FROM
    PersonDetails 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CSVToTable(@LIST) AS CSVToTable_1 ON PersonDetails.Id = CSVToTable_1.String 
INNER JOIN
    DealerTransactions ON PersonDetails.Id = DealerTransactions.FK_PersonDetails 
INNER JOIN
    DealerShops ON DealerTransactions.FK_ShopID = DealerShops.Id
```

The procedure is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectQuery_AllTransactionsByPersonPK]
    (@LIST VARCHAR)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT        
        PersonDetails.FirstName, PersonDetails.MiddleName, 
        PersonDetails.LastName, PersonDetails.DOB, PersonDetails.Gender, 
        CSVToTable_1.String AS SearchedID, 
        DealerTransactions.Address, DealerTransactions.AddressSuburb, 
        DealerTransactions.IDUsed, DealerTransactions.TransactionDate, 
        DealerTransactions.TransactionType, DealerTransactions.Item, 
        DealerTransactions.ItemDescription, DealerTransactions.SerialNumber, 
        DealerTransactions.TransactionNumber, DealerTransactions.ItemAmount, 
        DealerShops.ShopName
    FROM
        PersonDetails 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.CSVToTable(@LIST) AS CSVToTable_1 ON PersonDetails.Id = CAST(CSVToTable_1.String AS int) 
    INNER JOIN
        DealerTransactions ON PersonDetails.Id = DealerTransactions.FK_PersonDetails 
    INNER JOIN
        DealerShops ON DealerTransactions.FK_ShopID = DealerShops.Id
```

The CSV function is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] 
   (@StringInput VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ([String] VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                           ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                           LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ([String])
        VALUES (@String)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: can you post your stored proc?

Comment: I only see one variable @LIST.  How is it declared as the parameter?

Comment: Updated the original post to include the CSV function and the procedure

Comment: every in sql is scalar... you will need the size of the varchar

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a length to  @LIST varchar   such as `varchar(max)` or `varchar(50)`

**Example**

```
Declare @LIST varchar
Set @LIST = 'ABC'
Select @LIST
```

**Returns**

A

Comment: Bingo! Something so simple too.. Thank you. I'll accept the answer once enough time has passed.

Comment: @Lift  Happens to all of us.  I bet you looked at that 100 times and never saw it  :)  .  Happy it helped

Comment: @Lift FYI, I had a similar parse function and was amazed at the performance gains of using either the TALLY approach or XML.   Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084247/i-have-two-columns-with-multiple-values-that-i-need-to-parse-out/48084400#48084400 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082763/want-a-stored-procedure-for-comma-seperated-string-which-is-of-a-column-has-200/43082930#43082930